# xcode 5.5 inch simulators dont work, only black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I have a problem with xcode iphone simulator. all the 5.5 inch simulators dont work and only the 4.7 works. I have the latest xcode as well as the beta version, both. For the first time I made a very simple app for learning purposes and unable to simulate properly to check alignment on 5.5. Any idea how to fix?**

Comment: Can you paste a snippet of your AppDelegate code?

Comment: Hi Kunal, here is what I copied from the script:   (let me know if you mean something else)                                                   
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }